# Cannot retrieve data using java.util.UUID from Mysql db where primary key is binary(128)

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, uuid

Like the title says. I am storing entities in a `MySql DB` using `JPA` and `Hibernate`. I am using a `java.util.UUID` on the java side as my `@Id`. On the DB side the primary key is a `binary(128)`. Persisting works fine. No errors. But retrieving the data using the `UUID` as the key returns `null` every time. Looking in the database the hex used as the `binary` appears to match the `java.lang.String` representation of the `UUID` so everything seems to be getting translated smoothly. But like I said tests fail to confirm retrieval when retrieval is attempted. Switching to another datatype for my `@Id` isn't really an option because I need to know the `id` even before persistence and `UUID` is the best way to get a unique id without having to know the state of the DB. Here are my entity classes, the test that fails, and my schema definition.

schema def:

```
create table PLAYER(
ID binary(128) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
USERNAME VARCHAR(50) unique NOT NULL,
PASSWORD varchar(100) NOT NULL,
JOIN_DATE DATETIME);
```

`Player.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAYER")
public class Player extends AbstractEntity{

@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String username;

@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;


@Column(name = "JOIN_DATE")
private LocalDate joinDate;
```

`AbstractEntity.java`

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
protected UUID id;
```

Finally, the test that fails

```
    @Test
    void findById() {

    Player patrick = new Player();
    patrick.setId(uuid);
    patrick.setUsername("patrick");
    patrick.setPassword("password");
    patrick.setJoinDate(LocalDate.now());
    playerRepo.save(patrick);

    Optional<Player> result = playerRepo.findById(uuid);
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        fail();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add the columnDefinition property to Column annotation

```
@Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition="BINARY(128)")
protected UUID id;
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. The problem is that the program doesn't seem to understand the entity exists in the database. If i try and save an entity where the Player object is a field and is referenced by a foreign key in the DB, the program throws a ```TransientPropertyException```.

Comment: Yes..it is correct answer, since in db uuid field is stored as binary.
so as soon as I made the DDL and JPA configurations to be same, it started to work...

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct your test case in the following way:

```java
@Test
void findById() {

   Player patrick = new Player();
   // ...
   playerRepo.save(patrick);
   entityManager.flush();

   Optional<Player> result = playerRepo.findById(uuid);
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that before I wrote the question. Didn't make retrieval more successful.

Comment: What hibernate dialect and hibernate version do you use?